# Magento2: How can create individually custom dropdown of categories and subcategories?

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

I want to search products by parent categories and sub categories via search box. for example there is two dropdown "search by categories" and "search by sub categories". when we will select first dropdown value then according to first dropdown value, subcategories will be show in second dropdown and after then we can search item in search box.

I have tried with example of State city dropdown, but not getting good success. 
we need to do by PHP.
Anyone have an idea for that, how can we implement that?